# schema registry : Share partially/ authorization system

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

We need to share part of our Schema registry with another company and don't want them to see all the schemas. They also need to do the same for theirs.

Is there any way that each of us can share only part of our schema registry ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no.

Assuming each Schema Registry is hooked to a separate Kafka Clusters (call them `yours` and `theirs`), what you could do, is

1. Write a Kafka Streams application to `filter()` the messages you want them to see to a `_schemas_theirs` topic.
2. Use MirrorMaker, or Confluent Replicator, to copy your local `_schemas_theirs` topic to the `theirs` Cluster's `_schemas` topic that is being read by the other registry.
3. Have them do the same thing, copying their filtered data into `yours` Kafka Cluster's `_schemas` topic